# No module named constants

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I want to do sample application with Tastypie framework.

I added Tastypie to Installed app and modified `urls.py` as required, adding `from tastypie.api import Api`.  But when I open `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/?format=json`, I get the following exception:

> Exception Value: No module named constants

When I run:

```
pip install constants
```

everything looks ok.

```
Python 2.6 (and try on 2.7)
Django 1.4
Tastypie 0.10.0
```

Comment: [This](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/765) should help

Comment: Usually installing a _package_ won't help when you're missing a _module_, especially one named _constants_, add your entire stacktrace and urls.

Comment: from tastypie.api import Api
from api.resources import ApiData
v1_api = Api(api_name='v1')
v1_api.register(ApiData())

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
)

Comment: Just update django to 1.5. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

the problem is in the `resources.py` file for tastypie. It has the following line:

```
from django.db.models.constants import LOOKUP_SEP
```

That import will only work on 1.5+. For django < 1.5, it should be:

```
from django.db.models.sql.constants import LOOKUP_SEP
```

Upgrading to 1.5 will definitely fix it, but for those who can't, temporarily downgrade tastypie or do that fix yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Not really specific to `Tastypie` or Python 2.7, but I've seen the same error for `nrfutil` on Python 3.9.

The solution to this was downgrading Python to 3.8, where everything worked like a charm.