# No module named constants error

Tags: html, xml, django

I have a project in progress. In this project I have to change some reports that they implement by XML code.
When I run my project with "python manage.py runserver"it runs truthfully and I can change my XML code and see the HTML files on chrome but when I want to see the PDF file of reports I get an error that says:

```
>"IndexError, your list is out of range"
```

so I start to debug it, in this process debugger said

> "from django.db.models.constants import LOOKUP_SEP No module named constants".

this is whole trace back:

```
>Unhandled exception in thread started by <_pydev_bundle.pydev_monkey._NewThreadStartupWithTrace instance at 0x7f45ea1f3b48>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rajabi/pycharm-community-2017.1.4/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey.py", line 589, in __call__
    return self.original_func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 158, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 67, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 88, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/rajabi/Desktop/tina/clone-2017-07-05/rtis/src/saed/activities/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from saed.activities.base import models
  File "/home/rajabi/Desktop/tina/clone-2017-07-05/rtis/src/saed/activities/base/models.py", line 16, in <module>
    from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/model_utils/managers.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.db.models.constants import LOOKUP_SEP
ImportError: No module named constants
```

what should I do?

- django==1.4
- python==2.7.12
- tastypie == 0.9.16

I can't change my django and python version.

Comment: suggestion - django 1.4 is old try a new version

Comment: It's clearly not clear what you are trying to do. Please elaborate more.

Comment: first of all upgrade your django version to current release and the problem will be sovled

Comment: Most probably error is from external package. Post your full traceback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No module named constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191221/no-module-named-constants)

Answer (score 1):

This part of the traceback is showing you that the error is coming from django-model-utils.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/model_utils/managers.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.db.models.constants import LOOKUP_SEP
```

The [release notes](https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#300-20170413) say that support for Django 1.4 was dropped in version 3.0.

You could try installing an early version of django-model-utils, but really you should upgrade Django. Django 1.4 is years out of date and insecure.